# bsStyle of Bootstrap React doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have been working on boostrap react for 3 hours. I have tried to find questions and answers to my problem. bsStyle of Bootstrap React doesn't work at all, so i wonder it why? I have seen so many examples, and they just import like what i have done too.

```
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
```

but i still get a **simple button without any styles**
here my component

```
export class bsButton extends React.Component{
render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button bsStyle="primary">primary button</Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

what is wrong with my import or my component code?
your help is appreciated :D

Comment: Have you included the style sheets? https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html

Comment: Oh my god! I haven't read it and i never think i need to import raw bootstrap css file because i have it installed from npm. And i have material ui installed on my project too. Material ui doesn't have css so i just import its class name, then it will give me a nice style... but boostrap react...  anyway thanks for your idea

Comment: I have added an answer if you would mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make sure you have added the bootstrap CSS in the head of your page. 
[Getting Started](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/) This can be easily forgotten when adding the library through NPM

Comment: Yes! I used to install meteor package from atmospherejs.com, and i don't have to include in head or whatever. and i think npm package is similar to what i have known, but... different :D I use meteor + react to create web application. I will have many setbacks in my work. Thanks for your idea :D

Answer (score 6):

Include

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

in public/index.html

```
  <head>
  .
  .
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  .
  .
  </head>
```

source: [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html)